# Custom HTML Error Wrappers for Form Elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to find a way to customize the default error html

```
<div class="field_with_errors"></div>
```

To take my own classes:

```
     <div class="clearfix error">
        <label for="errorInput">Input with error</label>
        <div class="input">
          <input class="xlarge error" id="errorInput" name="errorInput" size="30" type="text">
          <span class="help-inline">Small snippet of help text</span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I have found this railscast from 2007 which uses Rails 2, I believe. http://railscasts.com/episodes/39-customize-field-error. It seems like Rails 3 might have a more friendly way to customize this html?

Also, it doesn't show a way to just add an error class directly to the input like I want.

Comment: in the code there is a `"` missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method explained in the link you posted is still used today with the [vanilla form builders in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-the-view).

So, if you wanted to wrap your input like you mention, create a method overriding the `ActionView::Base.field_error_proc` in your `environment.rb` file for example, like so:

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  if instance.error_message.kind_of?(Array)
    %(<div class="form-field error">#{html_tag}<small class="error">&nbsp;
      #{instance.error_message.join(',')}</small></div).html_safe
  else
    %(<div class="form-field error">#{html_tag}<small class="error">&nbsp;
      #{instance.error_message}</small></div).html_safe
  end
end
```

In the above code, I'm wrapping my input (the #{html_tag}) in a `<div class="form-field error>..</div>` that's the default used by [ZURB Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/). I'm also using a `<small class="error">...</small` tag (which is also the foundation default) to display the messages below the input.

However, I recommend using a form builder gem like [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form). It cleans up your view code quit a bit and allows for the level of customization you require.

Check out the railscast on it [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/234-simple-form).

Good luck!

Comment: would also probably recommend using simple_form.  If you are going to use the above code, it needs to be edited to close the trailing div  "#{instance.error_message}</small></div>).html_safe"